actualizar contador de elementos de un array asociado a un @Input()
Estoy practicando con un proyecto Angular 18.
Tengo un listado de todos con un formulario que los va añadiendo.
El componente que muestra el listado recibe los "todos" mediante un decorador @Input cada vez que se crea un "todo", tengo un contador para indicar en la vista el número de "todos" que no funciona, lo he intentado con signals.
El código del controlador:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  computed,
  Input,
  signal
} from '@angular/core';
import { TodoClass } from '../../../classes/TodoClass';
import { TodoComponent } from '../todo/todo.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uncompleted-todos',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TodoComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './uncompleted-todos.component.html',
})
export class UncompletedTodosComponent
{
  @Input() todos: Array<TodoClass> = [];

  total = signal<number>(this.todos.length);
  total2 = computed(() => this.todos.length);
}


Editado:

template:
<section class="mt-10 border border-gray-400 rounded p-2">
    <h4>Tareas pendientes {{ total() }} {{ total2() }}</h4>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let todo of todos">
        <app-todo [todo]="todo"></app-todo>
    </ng-container>
</section>

Los todos se van cargando correctamente.
Otra prueba, con ngOnChanges, sin señales, se imprime 2 en consola al iniciar el componente, no se detectan cambios:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  computed,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  signal,
  SimpleChanges
} from '@angular/core';
import { TodoClass } from '../../../classes/TodoClass';
import { TodoComponent } from '../todo/todo.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uncompleted-todos',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TodoComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './uncompleted-todos.component.html',
})
export class UncompletedTodosComponent implements OnChanges
{
  @Input() todos: Array<TodoClass> = [];

  myTodos: Array<TodoClass> = [];
  total = 0;
  total2 = 0;


  constructor()
  {
    this.myTodos = [...this.todos];
    // this.myTodos = this.todos; // mismo resultado
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void
  {
    if (changes['todos']
      && !changes['todos'].firstChange) {
      console.warn(1);
    }
    if (changes['todos']
      && changes['todos'].currentValue !== changes['todos'].previousValue) {
      console.warn(2);
    }
    if (changes['myTodos']
      && !changes['myTodos'].firstChange) {
      console.warn(3);
    }
    if (changes['myTodos']
      && changes['myTodos'].currentValue !== changes['myTodos'].previousValue) {
      console.warn(4);
    }
  }
}


No vemos cómo lo usas en el html, las preguntas deben incluir todos los datos. Aunque personalmente, no veo por qué necesitas  usar un segundo signal para algo que puedes obtener a partir del primero, basta con usar todos().lenght en el html.

@Benito-B no necesito un 2do signal, son pruebas que he hecho y no funcionan, solo intento detectar que el array asociado al @Input cambia su número de elementos.

Tareas pendientes {{ todos.length }} ¿Has probado solo llamando la propiedad length?

@Lobos no lo había probado, funciona.
